# How to get Visible properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties

Is there any way to get Visible propertie in CubeDimension in C#? I am looking for a way to do it in Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll, but I can't find it.

[image: properties]

Comment: do you mean this one?! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.cubedimension.visible.aspx

Comment: 'Visible' propertie which defined visibilty dimension for user

Comment: Yes, i will trie with this class. Already im trying to get this propertie using Dimension class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN documentations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.cubedimension.visible.aspx):

> Gets or sets the visibility property for a CubeDimension object.

```
public bool Visible { get; set; }
```

So simply get it from your `CubeDimension` object:

```
var dimention = new CubeDimension();
bool visibility = dimention.Visible;
```